# Hold variables in php for submit

Tags: php, textarea

I have several html textareas on my site.  Each has a submit button.  When a user types in one of the textareas i need to know which textarea this is.  These textareas are each assigned a number taken from a mysql database.  I can get the numbers out of the database, but how can I make it so that when a user types in a textarea and clicks submit the submit form knows which textarea this is.  Please ask to clarify if needed.  I tried my best to explain the problem. thanks.

p.s. the submit button just performs a mysql set values query.  I'm using php on my site.

for example: a textarea is assigned '3.'  When i submit this form i need 3 to be sent into my mysql set values query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a hidden input to store a reference for each form

```
<input type="hidden" name="database_reference" value="<?php echo $dbId; ?>" />
```

Then when you submit the form `$_POST['database_reference']` gives you the database id.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just give the textareas unique names? Adding a hidden input isn't a good solution if you can just call the textarea itself "data_reference_N" where N is "3" in this case.

Comment: @meagar wouldn't that be more of a problem? You'd then have to handle dynamic variable names, instead of having a consistent `datababase_reference` & `textarea_name` to work with.

Comment: @Ben It depends; neither solution is great. Ideally, if he has 5 submit forms, each should be posting to a unique URI representing the resource it is updating. If that isn't possible I'd rather see each text area represent a resource, rather than adding additional input fields when the existing form can do the same job.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="hidden" value="5" name="which_one" />
```

so for example

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <textearea name="text"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="which_one" />
    <input type="button" />
</form>
<form method="post" action="">
    <textearea name="text"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" value="2" name="which_one" />
    <input type="button" />
</form>
<form method="post" action="">
    <textearea name="text"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" value="3" name="which_one" />
    <input type="button" />
</form>
<form method="post" action="">
    <textearea name="text"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" value="4" name="which_one" />
    <input type="button" />
</form>
<form method="post" action="">
    <textearea name="text"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" value="5" name="which_one" />
    <input type="button" />
</form>
```

### UPDATE:

```
<?php
if ($_POST){
    include("db_connection.php");
    mysql_query("UPDATE table SET column = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['text'])."' WHERE value = ".intval($_POST['value']));
    echo "done";
}
?>
<form method="post" action="">
    <textearea name="text"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="which_one" />
    <input type="button" />
</form>
<form method="post" action="">
    <textearea name="text"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" value="2" name="which_one" />
    <input type="button" />
</form>
<form method="post" action="">
    <textearea name="text"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" value="3" name="which_one" />
    <input type="button" />
</form>
<form method="post" action="">
    <textearea name="text"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" value="4" name="which_one" />
    <input type="button" />
</form>
<form method="post" action="">
    <textearea name="text"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" value="5" name="which_one" />
    <input type="button" />
</form>
```

Comment: How can i use this "value" when i do the mysql query

Comment: @user802370: mysql query has nothing to do with this. you can get that value in PHP with $_POST['which_one']

Comment: sorry i still dont understand.  could you possiblyl do a simple mysql update values query?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have multiple `<form></form>` tags set up, one for each `<textarea>`, I would just add a hidden input field in each form. For example:

```
<form>
  <textarea />
  <input type="hidden" value="1" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
<form>
  <textarea />
  <input type="hidden" value="2" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

You can flesh it out from there, but you get the idea.

Comment: if you don't know enough HTML to flesh out the attributes I omitted, you probably don't have any business messing around with PHP and MySQL. Get a good HTML primer and start there.